# How do I use a UIImage as a section index title in iOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios8

I have a sectioned table view that has a "Recent Contacts" and "Favorites" section. I want to use an icon to represent them in the section index bar on the right-hand side. I am aware that you can set an icon for the search bar, but how can I generalize this and set an icon for any section? Worth noting that I am using Objective-C and not Swift on this project.

Cheers!

Comment: There is no way to have images in the section index down the right side of a table view. You can only specify text. Perhaps there is a Unicode symbol that meets your needs.

Comment: To add to what @rmaddy wrote above, you can't accomplish this with the built in functionality but you can build your own. There are a number of open source components that mimic the section index titles already so you can possibly customize one of those to support images as well as text. Here is one example I found: https://github.com/gdavis/GDIIndexBar

Comment: Sucks that it's not a built in functionality. Thank you all for the help!